# `is` attribute to initialize polymer component

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

We know from the `core-input` documentation that `core-input` is supposed to be used in this way:

`<input is="core-input">`

This way of using `is` attribute to initialize a polymer component seems not documented anywhere. Could anyone pointing me to the relevant documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`is` is the attribute for [native type extension](http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#type-extension-semantics) as defined in the W3C spec and is not specific to Polymer. In order to use the `is` attribute, the custom element must extend the appropriate native element's prototype.

```
document.registerElement('x-foo', {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLParagraphElement.prototype, {}),
  extends: 'p'
});

...

<p is="x-foo"></p>
```

Polymer 0.5 enables this type extension with the `extends` attribute:

```
<polymer-element name="x-foo" extends="p">
  ...
</polymer-element>

...

<p is="x-foo"></p>
```